# Filtering Sentinel-5P from metadata on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, date, sentinel-5p

I need a S5P image from a spesific date. Is there any way to filter image collection based on the metadata on GEE so the result is only from an image. I've tried something like:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2')
.select('SO2_column_number_density')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('time_reference_julian_day', 2459022.5 ))
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Which part do I need to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Your code would work, a functional equivalent alternative would be to use `.filterMetadata()`.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2')
.select('SO2_column_number_density')
.filterMetadata('time_reference_julian_day', 'equals', 2459022.5)
```

However there doesn't exist an Image at the time you selected, that's why 0 Images get returned

Instead you can use `.filterDate()` to display all images on the date you have chosen. Also please see the [get started](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/getstarted) part of the Developers Guide. It will help you immensly when you are starting out.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2') 
                    .select('SO2_column_number_density') 
                    .filterDate("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02")
 
print(collection)
```